# Handling None Values in Database Updates

Tags: python, sqlite, fastapi

I'm working on a Python application where I need to update database records based on user-provided settings. I have a method `saveSettings` that updates various settings in the database, but I'm encountering an issue with handling `None` values.

Here's my version of the method:

```
def saveSettings(self, name, font_size=None, bg_color=None, font_color=None, title_header=None, sorting_header=None):
    if not self._taskboard_exists(name):
        raise Exception(f"Taskboard '{name}' does not exist.")

    with self.global_db:
        cursor = self.global_db.cursor()

        # Check if the 'font_size', 'bg_color', 'font_color', 'title_header', and 'sorting_header' columns exist in the configuration table
        cursor.execute(f"PRAGMA table_info('{name}')")
        columns = cursor.fetchall()
        column_names = [column[1] for column in columns]

        # If any of the parameters are provided and the corresponding column doesn't exist, create it
        if font_size is not None and 'font_size' not in column_names:
            cursor.execute(f"ALTER TABLE '{name}' ADD COLUMN 'font_size' TEXT")
        if bg_color is not None and 'bg_color' not in column_names:
            cursor.execute(f"ALTER TABLE '{name}' ADD COLUMN 'bg_color' TEXT")
        if font_color is not None and 'font_color' not in column_names:
            cursor.execute(f"ALTER TABLE '{name}' ADD COLUMN 'font_color' TEXT")
        if title_header is not None and 'title_header' not in column_names:
            cursor.execute(f"ALTER TABLE '{name}' ADD COLUMN 'title_header' TEXT")
        if sorting_header is not None and 'sorting_header' not in column_names:
            cursor.execute(f"ALTER TABLE '{name}' ADD COLUMN 'sorting_header' TEXT")

        # Update the font size, background color, font color, title header, and sorting header in the configuration table for the taskboard
        update_query = f"UPDATE '{name}' SET "
        update_values = []

        if font_size is not None:
            update_query += "font_size = ?, "
            update_values.append(font_size)
        if bg_color is not None:
            update_query += "bg_color = ?, "
            update_values.append(bg_color)
        if font_color is not None:
            update_query += "font_color = ?, "
            update_values.append(font_color)
        if title_header is not None:
            update_query += "title_header = ?, "
            update_values.append(title_header)
        if sorting_header is not None:
            update_query += "sorting_header = ?, "
            update_values.append(sorting_header)

        # Remove the trailing comma and space from the query
        if update_query.endswith(", "):
            update_query = update_query[:-2]

        # Execute the update query with the values
        if update_values:
            cursor.execute(update_query, update_values)
            self.global_db.commit()
```

The problem is that when any of the parameters is `None`, the method sets the corresponding value in the database as empty, which is not the behavior I desire. Instead, I want to ensure that if a parameter is `None`, the corresponding value in the database remains unchanged.

I've tried modifying the method to conditionally construct the SQL update query and values, but I'm struggling to get it right. How can I adjust the method so that it only updates database values for parameters that are not `None`?

Comment: Looks ok to me (but could be written more concise if you use a dictionary with the values instead of single variables). The only other way I see is to use an sqlite SQL function like `coalesce` (something like `font_size = coalesce(?, font_size)`) but I don't know if this would be much better, especially because you have to check if the column `font_size` actually exists nevertheless.

Comment: If you have a function that *can* add, for example, a font size to a table, that table should probably just be defined with a `font_size` table to begin with. Having your function dynamically add a column seems like unnecessary complexity, and doubles the amount of code it apparently needs.

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose of this answer, I'm going to assume the necessary columns exist in the table (they probably should; is there any benefit to *not* just defining the columns in the first place?).

If you put the column names in one list and the argument values in another, you can iterate over both lists in parallel (using `zip`) to select the column/value pairs to include in the query.

You can then construct the `UPDATE` command from the list of selected column names using `', '.join` if necessary.

```py
def saveSettings(self, name, font_size=None, bg_color=None, font_color=None, title_header=None, sorting_header=None):
    if not self._taskboard_exists(name):
        raise Exception(f"Taskboard '{name}' does not exist.")

    values = [font_size, bg_color, font_color, title_header, sorting_header]

    # This can be hard-coded outside the function, since it's not
    # going to change.
    names = ['font_size', 'bg_color', 'font_color', 'title_header', 'sorting_header']

    update_columns = []
    update_values = []

    for column, value in zip(names, values):
        if value is not None:
            update_columns.append(f"{column} = ?")
            update_values.append(value)

    if not update_values:
        return  # Nothing to do

    with self.global_db:
        cursor = self.global_db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(
            f"UPDATE '{name}' SET " + ', '.join(update_columns),
            update_values
        )
        self.global_db.commit()
```

Also, consider using something like `sqlalchemy.sql` to avoid constructing SQL by hand like this.

Comment: This is not working. :(

Comment: What, exactly, doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged this with FastAPI, so I'm assuming you're using Pydantic as well. There is the `exclude_unset` attribute on Pydantic Schema that can remove fields not explicitly set when creating the model, which allows you to get a `dict` back of just the columns that have values to change.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class MySchema(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    font_size: Optional[int] = None
    font_color: Optional[str] = None

test_1 = MySchema(name='h', font_size=1, font_color='r')
test_1.model_dump(exclude_unset=True
#{'name': 'h', 'font_size': 1, 'font_color': 'r'}

test_2 = MySchema(name=None, font_size=1, font_color='r')
test_2.model_dump(exclude_unset=True)
#{'name': None, 'font_size': 1, 'font_color': 'r'}

test_3 = MySchema(font_size=1, font_color='r')
test_3.model_dump(exclude_unset=True)
#{'font_size': 1, 'font_color': 'r'}
```

If you then leverage an ORM like SQLAlchemy you don't have to write an SQL (which is more secure as you massively reduce your surface area for potential SQL injection).  You'd need to adapt this to your specific ORM, but you can get the general concept from the following code:

```
from YourORM import SQLBase, Column, Integer
class MySQLModel(SQLBase):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(length=5))
    font_size = Column(Integer)
    font_color = Column(String(length=5))

def save_settings(
    db: DB_Session,
    model_in: MySchema,
    sql_model: MySQLModel,
    primary_key_id: int
) -> MySQLModel:
    current_db_record = db.query(sql_model).filter(sql_model.id == primary_key_id).first() #There's normally a function to just retrieve via the primary key so might not need the filter.
    
    new_data_with_values_only = model_in.model_dump(exclude_unset=True)

    for k, v in new_data_with_values_only.items():
        setattr(current_db_record , k, v)

    db.add(current_db_record)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(current_db_record)
    return current_db_record
```